# Tradução de rotas MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internacionalização, asp.net-mvc-routing

Com o `ASP.Net MVC 4` estou querendo traduzir todas as minhas rotas, atualmente algumas estão assim:

```
http://localhost/pt-br
http://localhost/pt-br/sobre
http://localhost/pt-br/usuario/cadastro
```

Estou adicionando o idioma inglês e gostaria de utilizar a mesma Controller/Action e só alterar a rota para:

```
http://localhost/en-us
http://localhost/en-us/about
http://localhost/en-us/user/create
```

fiz algumas pesquisas no google, porém não encontrei nada parecido com este caso.
Até porque a minha segunda rota é personalizada e quase todas as minhas rotas são.
Gostaria apenas de saber qual é melhor forma para desenvolver isso.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Faça um arquivo de Resource apenas para rotas

Neste caso, padronize seu sistema para que cada Resource String seja o nome de um *Controller* ou o nome de uma *Action*. Não tem problema se repetir.

## 2. Faça um arquivo de rota para cada cultura

Esse passo é opcional, mas ajuda você a se organizar. Faça uma classe para cada rota envolvendo cultura que você gostaria que seu sistema tenha:

```
namespace SeuProjeto
{
    public class PtBrRouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "SobrePtBr",
                url: "pt-br/Sobre/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "About", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            ...

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "pt-br/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

## 3. Procure fazer o mapeamento dinâmico

Feita a separação, você pode ser o arquivo de Resources usando algo assim para montar suas rotas:

```
var resourceSet = MyResourceClass.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
                name: entry.Value,
                url: "pt-br/" + entry.Value + "/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = entry.Key, action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @Cigano pela a sua resposta, irei desenvolver aqui depois compartilho o resultado.